# Decoding gb-2312 file in colab

Tags: utf-8, google-colaboratory, gb2312

I am trying to open a file in Colab that uses gb-2312 encoding. Here is the code I *successfully* ran in my IDE to read and decode:

```
file = open(r'file.txt')
opened = file.read()
decoded = opened.encode('latin1').decode('gb2312')
print(decoded)
```

When I run this code in colab, I get the following error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 67: invalid continuation byte
```

But I can't decode without using read() or list() first, or else I get the following error:

```
'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

This seems like a catch-22. Is this a bug with Colab or is there some better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default when opening a file is `rt` (read, text mode) and uses an OS-specific default encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  Use the `encoding` parameter to override the default (which appears to be `utf-8`):

```py
with open('file.txt', encoding='gb2312') as file:
    data = file.read()
```